# Quicksort - ошибка stack overflow

Tags: c, алгоритм

Алгоритм сортирует таблицу со случайными числами на 100тыс, 500тыс, 1млн, но при сортировке уже отсортированной таблицы или таблицы обратно отсортированной выдает исключение Stack Overflow. Знаю, что это не хватает памяти, но как можно решить эту проблему?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

void quicksort(int *A, int p, int r);
int partition(int *A, int p, int r);

//int A[100000];
int A[500000];
//int A[1000000];

//int B[100000];
//int B[500000];
//int B[1000000];

//int C[100000];
//int C[500000];
//int C[1000000];

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int length = 500000;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        A[i] = i;
        //printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }

    /*for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        B[i] = i;
        //printf("%d ", B[i]);
    }*/

    /*for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        C[i] = i;
        printf("%d ", C[i]);
    }*/

    float start = GetTickCount();
    quicksort(A, 0, 499999);
    float finish = GetTickCount();
    float result = (finish - start) / 1000;

    printf("\n losowa (seconds): %f", result);

    getchar();
}

void quicksort(int *A, int p, int r)
{
    float start = GetTickCount();
    int q;
    if (p < r) {
        q = partition(A, p, r);
        quicksort(A, p, q - 1);
        quicksort(A, q + 1, r);
        float finish = GetTickCount();
        float result = (finish - start) / 1000;
    }
}

int partition(int *A, int p, int r)
{
    int i, j, x, tmp;

    x = A[r];
    i = p - 1;

    for (j = p; j <= r - 1; j++) {
        if (A[j] <= x) {
            i++;

            tmp = A[j];
            A[j] = A[i];
            A[i] = tmp;
        }
    }

    tmp = A[i + 1];
    A[i + 1] = A[r];
    A[r] = tmp;

    return i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> как можно решить эту проблему?

Использовать нерекурсивную реализацию QuickSort. Подробных разборов с исходниками на C много, например, [здесь](http://algolist.manual.ru/sort/quick_sort.php).

(а может и вообще подумать о другом алгоритме, не quicksort, так как из примера не очень понятно: речь идёт о реальных данных или об учебном примере)

Comment: И чем  же плох quicksort?

Comment: @avp, возможно, ответ знает тот, кто утверждает что он плох?

Comment: Так Вы же и пишете -- "а может и вообще подумать о другом алгоритме, не quicksort"

Comment: @avp, но не "quicksort плох". Как часто вам приходится сортировать миллион интов? Мне - никогда (точнее, приходится и миллионы сортировать по целочисленным ключам, но на этом уровне пусть БД пыжится). А вот, например, строить деревья для дальнейшего поиска по ним, причём нетолько по числовым ключам, а то и по составным - часто. В общем, для разных целей разные пути могут быть. Не говоря уж о том, что если даже голые инты, но их пара десятков, то вставки рулят. Даже странно, что такие вещи приходится объяснять.

Comment: В самом деле. Лучше объяснить другое (относящееся к вопросу). А именно, как усовершенствовать используемый ТС алгоритм, чтобы он начал работать. Алгоритм по Вашей ссылке (неважно, рекурсивный или нет), работает вот из-за этого -- `// Шаги 2, 3. Отправляем большую часть в стек  и двигаем lb,ub`. Также желательно рассмотреть алгоритм выбора разделяющего элемента (`pivot`). Сейчас у ТС такой выбор, что для упорядоченного массива получится время O(n ^ 2), а не O(n log n). Еще можно упомянуть о преходе к более простому алгоритму сортировки, когда сортируемый отрезок становится коротким. И т.д.

Comment: А если совсем по делу, то ответ `Использовать нерекурсивную реализацию QuickSort` не совсем верен. Работать будет любая реализация, при условии, что в стек отправляется большая часть массива. Т.е. продолжаем делить (первая часть рекурсии) более короткую. В таком случае глубина рекурсии (или требуемый размер стека) в худшем случае (каждый раз делим пополам) составит log(n) (n - размер исходного массива, для 1 млн получим 20)

Comment: @avp, надо профилировать. Накладные расходы на рекурсию в любом случае есть, но насколько они влияют, и насколько это критично в конкретном случае - ?

Comment: В конкретном случае ошибка, как пишет ТС, это **Stack Overflow**, а не время работы. А по времени (даже без профилировок), не спорю, нерекурсивная версия будет быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Навскидку несколько вариантов:

1. Увеличить размер используемого стека (см. ключи компилятора)
2. Сократить количество передаваемых аргументов (они то как раз и пихаются в стек вызовов) - в вашем случае очевидный кандидат это параметр `int *a` - можно например его сделать глобальным
3. Засунуть все параметры в динамический массив типа `Stack` и извлекать их вручную

Answer (score 0):

После `q = partition(A, p, r);` посмотреть, какой из "подмассивов" короче и продолжать рекурсию с него

```
if (q - 1 - p < r - q + 1) {
    quicksort(A, p, q - 1);
    quicksort(A, q + 1, r);
} else {
    quicksort(A, q + 1, r);
    quicksort(A, p, q - 1);
}
```